# Can't find where pycharm is installed

Tags: linux, ubuntu, pycharm

I am new to Linux. I downloaded PyCharm for python using:

```
sudo snap install pycharm-community --classic
```

I want to open it but could not. I typed `./pycharm` in the command prompt but does not work. I opened the `Download` and `usr/bin` and `bin` folders to run the Shell code. I find the `Download` empty although I am sure the program installed and nothing in the `bin`.

I also tried:

```
$ whereis pycharm
```

It outputs this:

```
pycharm:
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I tried that command in Ubuntu 17.10. After the installation, PyCharm was installed at `/snap/pycharm-community`. And the PyCharm startup script `pycharm.sh` is under `/snap/pycharm-community/current/bin`.

If you want to start PyCharm through command line, maybe you should run:

```
pycharm-community
```

instead of `pycharm` (if you are using PyCharm Professional, similarily, use `pycharm-professional`).

A better way to start PyCharm is through `activity`, press <kbd>super</kbd> and input `pycharm`, the application will appear.

PS:

I got the command `pycharm-community` through [Tab Completion](https://www.howtogeek.com/195207/use-tab-completion-to-type-commands-faster-on-any-operating-system/).

Comment: Thaks. But what is `super`? I am windows user so I can not see this button?

Comment: @anonymous see the picture: [https://i.loli.net/2018/02/10/5a7edbbbbe89d.jpg](https://i.loli.net/2018/02/10/5a7edbbbbe89d.jpg)

Comment: Ah. It is called `Home`.